# How do I make arp -a scan console results into table format in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, console, output

my code

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    try {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("arp -a ");
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
        // read the output from the command
        String ps = null;
        while ((ps = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(ps);
            // read any errors from the attempted command
            while ((ps = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.err.println(ps);
            }
        }
    }catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}
```

my console output is

```
Interface: 192.168.201.1 --- 0x6
Internet Address Physical Address Type
192.168.201.2 48-88-ca-c8-87-4a static
192.168.201.4 00-6f-64-be-6e-e8 static
192.168.201.255 ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff static
224.0.0.2 01-00-5e-00-00-02 static
224.0.0.22 01-00-5e-00-00-16 static
224.0.0.251 01-00-5e-00-00-fb static
224.0.0.252 01-00-5e-00-00-fc static
224.0.0.253 01-00-5e-00-00-fd static
224.0.1.60 01-00-5e-00-01-3c static
239.192.152.143 01-00-5e-40-98-8f static
239.255.100.100 01-00-5e-7f-64-64 static
239.255.255.250 01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa static
239.255.255.253 01-00-5e-7f-ff-fd static
255.255.255.255 ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff static
```

I want this output should be displayed in table format..please say me how to do it.
Reply

Comment: Please learn how to use markdown.  I fixed your formatting this time.  As to your request _"say me how to do it"_ that is not how StackOverflow works. We do not do your work for you.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn what is on-topic here.

Comment: okay.....so give suggestion for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace the line

```
System.out.println(ps);
```

with the following,

```
if (ps.matches("^(Internet\\s|\\d{1,3}\\.).*")) {
    System.out.printf("%-18s %-18s %s\n", (Object[]) ps.split("\\s++(?!Address)"));
} else {
    System.out.println(ps);
}
```

the output will look like this:

```
Interface: 192.168.201.1 --- 0x6
Internet Address   Physical Address   Type
192.168.201.2      48-88-ca-c8-87-4a  static
192.168.201.4      00-6f-64-be-6e-e8  static
192.168.201.255    ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff  static
224.0.0.2          01-00-5e-00-00-02  static
224.0.0.22         01-00-5e-00-00-16  static
224.0.0.251        01-00-5e-00-00-fb  static
224.0.0.252        01-00-5e-00-00-fc  static
224.0.0.253        01-00-5e-00-00-fd  static
224.0.1.60         01-00-5e-00-01-3c  static
239.192.152.143    01-00-5e-40-98-8f  static
239.255.100.100    01-00-5e-7f-64-64  static
239.255.255.250    01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa  static
239.255.255.253    01-00-5e-7f-ff-fd  static
255.255.255.255    ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff  static
```

See [*Format String Syntax*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for details.

Comment: Don't you get the output that I put in the answer? Or do you want something else?

Comment: even after applying your code it shows the output with table border line..  Interface: 192.168.201.1 --- 0x6
Internet Address   Physical Address   Type
192.168.201.2      48-88-ca-c8-87-4a  static
192.168.201.4      00-6f-64-be-6e-e8  static
192.168.201.255    ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff  static
224.0.0.2          01-00-5e-00-00-02  static
224.0.0.22         01-00-5e-00-00-16  static
224.0.0.251        01-00-5e-00-00-fb  static
224.0.0.252        01-00-5e-00-00-fc  static
224.0.0.253        01-00-5e-00-00-fd  static
224.0.1.60         01-00-5e-00-01-3c  static

Comment: Could you please extend your question by the expected output? The preformatting is lost in comments.